# Rotation angles in the 3D space from 2D projection.

Tags: geometry

I'm detecting the position of the 4 corners of a paper sheet with a camera.

This is only giving me 4 points (x,y) in the 2D space (projection of the paper on the screen).

Knowing the size of the paper, is there a way to find out the rotation/tilting angles in every axis?

Consider the initial position as perpendicular to the camera, so rotation angles are 0 and the points correspond to the corners of a rectangle with the size of the sheet of paper. There is no translation (in the pictures there is a slight translation, but it will be properly calibrated in the end).

Please, feel free to edit the question as I might not be clear enough.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Initial]

[image: Tilted]

Comment: Is the page rotated about its center then?

Comment: Yes, the rotation is in any of the axis x, y, z with origin in the center.

Comment: Essentially, the camera doesn't 'see' the $x$, $y$ coordinates. If you consider spherical coordinates and make the camera the origin, then you can say that the camera 'sees' the $\theta$, $\phi$ coordinates. 

I've tried approaching this problem exactly without approximation but it gets very complicated and I'm not sure how to proceed. What is the approximate ratio $d:w$ where $d$ is the distance of the paper from the camera, and $w$ the longer edge length of the paper?

Knowing this, it may be possible to do a sufficient approximation.